# Selective Schema dump using pg_dump

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump

I am new to Postgres and my task is to back up and restore one PG Database to Another , my source Postgres DB has 150 schemas but my task to selectively dump only 75 from 150 and restore the 75 into a new DB server, I plan to use pg_dump for the same. The 75 which I need to exclude from the list have a similar name all start with name PatSchema_x, x can be 1,2,3....N. Is there a was I can pass the Schema name pattern like 'PatSchema' to pg_dump so that it excludes all these schemas and dumps only the remaining ones. Pls let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-N` option, like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) describes:

> `-N pattern`
> `--exclude-schema=pattern`
>
> Do not dump any schemas matching `pattern`. The pattern is interpreted according to the same rules as for `-n`.

So try

```sh
-N "PatSchema_*"
```